# Why is mixed mode authentication not recommended?

Tags: sql-server

I have a class called Planning and Auditing of Information Systems and I came upon a exam question that goes like this:

Why is it not recommended to use "SQL Server and Windows authentication mode" for authenticating to a Microsoft SQL database?

I searched the literature I have for this and googled it but I wasn't able to find a definitive answer for this question. Does anyone know what this question could be aiming at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just my opinion, of course, but the reason it isn't recommended is that you end up having 2 different sets of users that have to be maintained and monitored at all times.  In the real world this usually ends up with one of those two groups being neglected or not properly maintained, oftentimes because the sysadmins maintain the Windows Auth users and the DBAs maintain the SQL Server users.  This inconsistency can lead to security concerns, or issues where users end up with both a Windows Auth username/password and a SQL Server username/password.  When deactivating users sometimes only one of the two accounts will get deactivated, leading to a possible security issue.

Answer (score 2):

When a SQL Server instance is brought up using Mixed authentication, the "sa" logon is enabled with complete sysadmin privileges and is given a password (hopefully a very strong one). The "sa" account is a common point of attack.

A hacker with access to an instance's "sa" account not only has all the data on the compromised instance and any linked servers, he also wields the power of the service account which the instance is running under by using xp_cmdshell to call PowerShell scripts among other things. Many organizations do not follow best practices for service accounts, and they will have their entire production environment running under one or two service accounts. This makes the "sa" account a very attractive point of attack for a hacker.

Under Windows authentication, the "sa" logon is disabled. This is probably what your exam question is looking for.

Mike Walston's points are also very true.